# Save file uploaded in Django without a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to save a file and do something to it a from in an html file, I am not using django forms but I am using django for backend and I don't need a database since I don't want to keep any of the files. I tried what the django documentation has instructed.

html file

```
 <input type="file" id="face_files" name="face_files" multiple >
```

view.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InputForm(request)
        call_form_function(form)
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Inputform.py

```
class InputForm():

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.face_files = request.FILES.getlist('face_files')
        # print('face_files= ', self.face_files)
        self.face_name = request.POST.get('face_name')
        # print('face_name= ', self.face_name)

    def save_files(self):
        import os
        self.delete_temp()
        folder = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/static/temp/'+self.face_name
        try:
            os.mkdir(folder)
            counter=1
            for file in self.face_files:
                # print(file)
                destination=open(folder +"/face"+str(counter)+".jpg", 'wb+')
                for chunk in file.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
                destination.close()
                counter+=1
        except:
            with open(console_html_path, "w+") as f:
                f.write(traceback.format_exc())
                traceback.print_exc()
        return folder


    def do_function(self):
        folder_path = self.save_files()
        function(args, folder_path)

def call_form_function(form):
    import threading
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=form.do_function)
    t1.start()
```

But I get the error

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py", line 91, in chunks
    self.file.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your view?

Comment: Can you paste a little bit more of your files?

Comment: @IainShelvington I edited the question with views.py and InputForm.

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic my file is a .jpg, the first binary line is as follows: `b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x02\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x01\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x04\x03\x02\x02\x02\x02\x05\x04\x04\x03\x04\x06\x05\x06\x06\x06\x05\x06\x06\x06\x07\t\x08\x06\x07\t\x07\x06\x06\x08\x0b\x08\t\n'`

Comment: @Moe when I sadi "files" I ment Django files :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate function to handle the uploaded file.

```
def handle_uploaded_files(f):
    with open(f'uploaded/folder/path/{f.name}', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```